# Coriander steep technique

Tags: beer, spices

If I crack or grind coriander for a steep at the end of a boil, will it settle out or should I pour through a strainer when transferring to to primary?  Should I add before or after flameout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I normally just add coriander in the last 5-10 minutes of the boil.  I usually crack it.  Most of it will simply precipitate to the bottom.  By the time you are done transferring from the boil pot and then out of the primary those bits are gone.  That's been my experience anyway.